# Unable to SSH in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am facing a strange issue. Currently I am working over deployment and configuration of few services over AWS over multiple instances. I have been creating multiple EC2 Instances and deploying required services over it. To start my jars, I have written a script. Ubuntu asks me to broaden the permissions for running the script. Since it is a test server, I have been granting 777 permissions to the ubuntu user as below -

**Ubuntu User Home Path** = /home/ubuntu, **Script Path** = /home/ubuntu/IASQueueBuilder/scripts

I am not sure what exactly goes wrong but after few mins, I get kicked out of ssh and then I can never ssh again to that instance.

To troubleshoot this, I have created a new instance and this time just gave 777 permissions to the script I have to run and nothing strange  happens.

Can anyone help me figure the reasoning behind this? I have done some homework and I could see there are multiple issues with ssh to AWS Instances. Few are as below -
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=765025
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=246274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've messed up the `/home/user/.ssh` directory permissions, that's why you can't access your instance now. The `.ssh` directory should have 700 permissions. You can fix this and access your instance by doing the following:

1. Stop your instance
2. Detach the volume
3. Create new instance
4. Attach the volume from your problematic instance to the new instance
5. Mount it on /mnt/something or where ever you want so that you could
   have access to it

Manually fix the permissions of `.ssh` directory. One you're done, detach the volume from instance #2 and attach it to your main instance.

Also, consider snapshot-ing your instances, or at least the one with important data. It never hurts to have a backup.

Comment: You are right. It seems the permissions for the keys should be more restrictive. Thanks!!

Comment: You might also consider using a different user to run your script, not the one you use to manage your instance. Just saying :)

Comment: that's again a good idea. Right now I am doing this as a part of POC but your suggestion could be taken in account when I move it to Production. Thanks once again :)